# How to prove that $2n\le2^n$

Tags: inequality

How to prove that $2n \le 2^n$ for any $n\in\Bbb{N}$? I proved to use the induction but unfortunately I don't be able to conclude something. So could someone help me, please?

Comment: @UmbertoP. I edited it now.

Comment: If $n=1$ this says $2 \le 2$. Otherwise you can divide by $2$ and prove that $n \le 2^{n-1}$ for all $n \in \mathbf N$. You can do this by induction.

Comment: Try induction , have you considered it ?

Comment: Is your question *why* it is true?  Or is your question *how* to put it into a proof?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The case $n=1$ works. Suppose $2k\le 2^k$ with $k\in\Bbb N$. Since $k\ge1$, $2k+2\le4k\le2\cdot2^k=2^{k+1}$. This completes the inductive step.

Comment: Why not just provide a hint?

Comment: @J.G. Okay. Why do you say that the case $n=1$ works? Indeed if we want use induction we must verify the inequality first for $k=0$ and then suppose that it is true for some $k\ge 1$ and then we can prove that it is true for $k+1$, right? Anyway the case $n=0$ is trivially. My observation is only for rigour.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro You didn't indicate whether you define $\Bbb N$ to start at $0$ or $1$. As I've stated it, the inductive step needs to assume $k\ge1$. If you want to prove the $n=0$ case too, it needs to be part of an unusually expanded base step.

Comment: "we must verify the inequality first for k=0 and then suppose that it is true for some k≥1"  No!  That's a sure way to get "all horses are the same color error"  If you start and $k = a$ then you must suppose it is true for some $k \ge a$.  If you start at $k =0$ then you suppose it is true for some $k \ge 0$  (!!!!!**NOT**!!!!! $k \ge 1$).  And if you start at $k=1$ then you suppose it is true for some $k \ge 1$.   And if you start at $k = 5$ then you supposed it is true for some $k \ge 5$.  You must start at the beginning but the is no law that says the beginning is $0$.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_horses_are_the_same_color) to understand fleabood's comment about horses.

Comment: @J.G Okay, so your proof is not valid if the sequence start form $0$?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro I proved an inductive step works from any $k\ge1$ to $k+1$. Therefore, the proof is valid provided it includes a base step for each desired $n\le1$. Whether that includes $n=0$ depends on your definition of $\Bbb N$.

Comment: Okay, it is celar! Thanks too much!

Answer (score 1):

For a proof without induction $$2^n = (1+1)^n =  {n\choose n}+{n\choose n-1}+...{n\choose 1}+ {n\choose 0}$$

for $n\gt2 $ this amounts to $ 1+n+...+n+1 = 2n+2+...$

Answer (score 0):

1)

$2n = \underbrace{2 + 2 + ..... + 2}_{n\text{ times}}$

$2^n = 2*2^{n-1} = 2^{n-1} + 2^{n-1} = $

$2^{n-1} + (2*2^{n-2})= 2^{n-1} + (2^{n-2} + 2^{n-2}) = 2^{n-1} + 2^{n-2}+2^{n-2}=$

$2^{n-1} + 2^{n-2} + (2*2^{n-3})= 2^{n-1} + 2^{n-2} + (2^{n-3} + 2^{n-3}) = 2^{n-1} + 2^{n-2} + 2^{n-3}+2^{n-3}=$

.....

$\underbrace{2^{n-1} + 2^{n-2} + 2^{n-3} + ......... + 2^1 + 2^1}_{n\text{ terms}} $

2)

Let $2n = M$.

$2(n+1) = 2n + 2 = M + 2$.

Let $2^n = N$.  then $2^{n+1} = 2^n*2 = N*2= N + N=N + 2^n$.

So going from $2n$ to $2(n+1)$ the value increases by $2$.

Going from $2^n$ to $2^{n+1}$ then value increases by $2^n$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple proof without induction :

Let $ n\in\mathbb{N}^{*} $, We have that $ \left(\forall k\in\mathbb{N}^{*}\right),\ 1+\frac{1}{k}\leq 2 $, Thus : $$ \prod_{k=1}^{n-1}{\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)}\leq\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}{2} \iff n\leq 2^{n-1}\iff 2n\leq 2^{n} $$

Since the inequality stands for $ n=0 $, we have : $$ \left(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\right),\ 2n\leq 2^{n} $$