# An obvious inequality

Tags: inequality

Prove that $2^{k-1} \ge k$ for $k\ge 1$. It seems obvious as the rate of increasing the power of $2$ is much greater than that of natural numbers. I tried to prove it by induction. As the base case, we can see that k=1 satisfies and is the equality case. So we assume $2^{n-1} \ge n$ to be true and try to prove that $2^n \ge n+1$. Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3951182/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3603509/42969

Answer (score 3):

If $n\geq 1$ then
$$2^n = 2\cdot 2^{n-1}\overset{\text{(IH)}}{\geq} 2\cdot n = n + n \geq n + 1$$